# 3 biological groups, 30 subjects (total), measured on 10 days - how to correct for day-to-day variation?

Tags: variance, normalization

We've run an experiment in which we included 90 subjects and have measured several variables.

My question specifically goes to the way we can correct for day-to-day variations. So, here is the setup of the experiment.

- 3 groups of 10 subjects
- Those groups are measured on 10 different days (each day includes 1 subject of each group)

I was considering the paired t-test, but it does not seem appropriate (typically explained as "before" and "after" treatment).

Another way I was considering, is to calculate the average per day, and to normalize my data. [i.e. average of 50, based on 3 subjects, on day 1. Sample from group 1 had e.g. 40 (normalized 0.8), sample from group 2 e.g. 50 (normalized 1.0), sample from group 3 e.g. 60 (normalized 1.2).

And so on, for each experimental day.

Looking forward to any reply for suggestions (and I'm mainly using GraphPad Prism 5 - so not very sophisticated in SPSS for instance)